# SQL percentage of rows for non numeric data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that I've setup to have the following:

```
SampleID | Status    | Due              | TurnAroundTimeinDays | DateReceived
---------+-----------+------------------+----------------------+-----------------
1        | Prepared  | 2016-06-06 14:00 | 120                  | 2016-05-05 10:00
2        | Available | 2016-07-06 14:00 | 10                   | 2016-05-05 10:00
3        | Done      | 2016-07-06 14:00 | 120                  | 2016-05-05 10:00
```

Sample 1 was received on May 5th, and has 120 days to be completed so it is not due.
Sample 2 is clearly late and is overdue.
If the status on Sample 2 was changed to Done then it would not be late.
I would like to know if there is a way to get the percent of all the overdue items with a status that is not set as Done.

I tried to use row counts but am not having any luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query should look something like this:

```
SELECT (
    (
       SELECT Count(*) FROM table_name WHERE your_condition
    )* 100 / Count(*)  
) AS Percentage
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Aren't the denominator and numerator switched? I want my condition / total. I tried to change the order around but that didn't work.